# Recursions in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, combinations

I got a task of making combinations of elements in n- number of sets. Such that no elements of one sets combines with itself. The structure being:

> Products ---> Controls ---> LOVs [List of Values]
>
> Sample scenario:
>
> 1 Product --> has 3 controls control 1 --> has 3 LOV's control 2 -->
>   has 2 LOV's control 3 --> has 5 LOV's
>
> No. Of possible combinations of Product 1: 3*2*5 = 30.

Being a programmer -and a noob in SQL- i immediately resorted to recursions. I dont know about the efficiency of recursions in in PL/SQL. But i got the required result by traversing through all the controls like a tree and picking up values at the leaves. The solution works but if it was to be done without recursions what could be the possible way?

```
procedure postcombinations(pProductID in varchar2,
                           lovs       in varchar2,
                           ctrl       in varchar2) is
  lv_cp varchar2(100);
  lv_cl varchar2(100);
begin

  -- Loop through All the controls defined against a product other
  -- than the ones already traversed (Not in condition) also 
  -- restrict results to One branch since order is doesn't matter.

  for i in (select cp.control_id
              from tbl_control_product cp, tbl_control c
             where cp.product_id = pProductID
               and cp.control_id = c.control_id
               and c.control_type = 2
               and cp.control_id not in
                   (select regexp_substr(ctrl, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                      from dual
                    connect by regexp_substr(ctrl, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
               and rownum < 2) loop
    begin

      -- Loop through all the LOV's in the controls and append them to Input 
      --to recurse the function 
      for p in (select cl.lov_id
                  from tbl_control_lov cl
                 where cl.control_id = i.control_id) loop
        if lovs is not null then
          pkg_product.postcombinations(pProductID => pProductID,
                                       lovs       => lovs || ',' ||
                                                     p.lov_id,
                                       ctrl       => ctrl || ',' ||
                                                     i.control_id);
        else
          pkg_product.postcombinations(pProductID => pProductID,
                                       lovs       => lovs,
                                       ctrl       => ctrl || ',' ||
                                                     i.control_id);
        end if;

      end loop;
    end;
  end loop;

  -- When A leaf is encountered the select statement returns a null 
  --the inputs are dumped into a table and voila.
  begin
    select cp.control_id
      into lv_cp

      from tbl_control_product cp, tbl_control tc
     where cp.product_id = pProductID
       and cp.control_id = tc.control_id
       and tc.control_type = 2
       and cp.control_id not in
           (select regexp_substr(ctrl, '[^,]+', 1, level)
              from dual
            connect by regexp_substr(ctrl, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
       and rownum < 2;
  Exception
    When NO_DATA_FOUND then
      insert into tbl_test values (ctrl, lovs);
      commit;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Just for your info, check this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're doing, but this would give you the 30 combinations of `control_id` and `lov_id` for a single product:

```
select tcp.control_id, tcl.lov_id
from tbl_control_product tcp
join tbl_control tc on tc.control_id = tcp.control_id
cross join tbl_control_lov tcl
where tcp.product_id = <productID>
and tc.control_type = 2;
```

Each of the three controls sees each of the 10 LOVs for any of them.

But from what I think your procedure is doing, it appears that if there are three controls for the product you want to list those controls, and all combinations of LOVs that come under them. Your procedure seems to have a bug in the `else` - I think you need `lovs => p.lov_id` there rather than `lovs => lovs`; with that change the initial call can have `lovs => null`. But you seem to have to pass an initial number for `ctrls`, which spoils the output. If I've followed it and created data properly (see Fiddle below) then you end up inserting something like this, if called as `pkg_product.postcombinations(pProductID => 'ABC', lovs => null, ctrl => '0')`:

```
ctrl 0,11,12,13 lovs 101,201,301
ctrl 0,11,12,13 lovs 101,201,302
ctrl 0,11,12,13 lovs 101,201,303
...
ctrl 0,11,12,13 lovs 103,202,304
ctrl 0,11,12,13 lovs 103,202,305
```

If that's right then you can do the same thing with a single SQL statement, as long as you're using 11gR2 as it uses recursive subquery factoring:

```
with t as (
  select tcp.control_id, tcl.lov_id,
    dense_rank() over (partition by tcp.product_id
      order by tcp.control_id) as control_num,
    count(distinct tcp.control_id)
      over (partition by tcp.product_id) as control_count
  from tbl_control_product tcp
  join tbl_control tc on tc.control_id = tcp.control_id
  join tbl_control_lov tcl on tcl.control_id = tc.control_id
  where tcp.product_id = 'ABC'
  and tc.control_type = 2
),
r (control_num, control_count, ctrl, lovs) as (
  select control_num, control_count, to_char(control_id), to_char(lov_id)
  from t
  where control_num = 1
  union all
  select t.control_num, t.control_count,
    ctrl ||','|| control_id, lovs ||','|| lov_id
  from r
  join t on t.control_num = r.control_num + 1
)
select ctrl, lovs
from r
where control_num = control_count
order by ctrl, lovs;
```

Which is pretty much the same logic you're using, kinda. And that gives:

```
CTRL                 LOVS               
-------------------- --------------------
11,12,13             101,201,301          
11,12,13             101,201,302          
11,12,13             101,201,303          
...
11,12,13             103,202,304          
11,12,13             103,202,305
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77fa8/1).

Comment: It might be possible to do this with a hierarchical query and aggregation too, but I couldn't see an obvious way.